# get data from datalayer into observablecollection in View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I get data from a DataLayer Class into the ViewModel but it doesn't get into the observableCollection that is binded with the listbox in the View.

```
public class ViewModel : NotifyUIBase
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
         FindImageCommand = new RelayCommand(FindImage);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Image> FindVisualReferences { get; set; }       
    public RelayCommand FindImageCommand { get; private set; }

    private void FindImage()
    {
         string SearchTerm = this.SearchBox;
         var dbFunctions = new DatabaseFunctions();
         FindVisualReferences = dbFunctions.FindVisualReferences(SearchTerm);
    }
}
```

I've tested the `FindVisualReferecences(SearchTerm)` Method and it gives the items needed to fill the observableCollection.
I also tested the databinding with the View and that's working to.

When I place the method in the constructor the ObservableCollection gets filled

```
  public ViewModel()
    {
         var dbFunctions = new DatabaseFunctions();
         FindVisualReferences = dbFunctions.FindVisualReferences(SearchTerm);
    }
```

But I need to call the method when the user is gives the FindImageCommand.
How can I make this work? I'm really a rookie when it comes to coding.

Comment: what's the problem ? 
are you not executing FindImageCommand ?

Comment: How do you activate the command? through a button or something like that?

Comment: The command executes and and I can get the data into the ViewModel, but somehow it doesn't reach the ObservableCollection in the ViewModel, although the FindVisualReferences in the FindImage Method holds the items that I need for the ObservableCollection to bind with the View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your setting your FindVisualReference property with a new instance of ObservableCollection instead of adding and removing from your existing one.

```
public ObservableCollection<Image> FindVisualReferences { get; set; }

private void FindImage()
{
     string SearchTerm = this.SearchBox;
     var dbFunctions = new DatabaseFunctions();
     FindVisualReferences.Clear();
     FindVisualReferences.AddRange(dbFunctions.FindVisualReferences(SearchTerm));
}
```

Alternatively you can do as you've done and set the property

```
FindVisualReferences = dbFunctions.FindVisualReferences(SearchTerm);
```

but in order for this to work you would have to Raise the PropertyChanged event.

```
private ObservableCollection<Image> _findVisualReferences;
public ObservableCollection<Image> FindVisualReferences 
{ 
   get{ return _findVisualReferences;}
   set
   {
       _findVisualReferences = value;
       RaiseProperyChanged("FindVisualReferences");
   }
}
```

But if your doing that there's not much point in using an ObservableCollection to being with so just use List instead.

My suggestion , make it a readonly property (i.e. getter only) and add to it.

```
private ObservableCollection<Image> _findVisualReferences;
public ObservableCollection<Image> FindVisualReferences 
{ 
   get
   {
       if(_findVisualReferences == null)
          _findVisualReferences = new ObservableCollection<Image>(); 
       return _findVisualReferences;
   }       
}
```